# Laravel. Error trying to get value of column from relationship using eloquent

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get the value of the column from another table that I return using pagination, **the first page works** but when I tried to go to the **2nd page I got the error** "Trying to get property 'image' of non-object", what seems to be the problem?

Controller

```
$products = Products::paginate(6);
return view('products', ['products' => $products]);
```

View

```
@foreach ($products as $p)
     <a href="#"><img src="{{ asset('images/products/'.$p->images->first()->image ) }}" alt=""></a>
@endforeach
```

Model Products

```
protected $table = 'products';

protected $primaryKey = 'id_product';

protected $fillable = [
    'id_product', 'product_name', 'product_desc', 'product_price', 'product_edition', 'id_product_type', 'id_material', 'product_discount', 'product_age'
];

public function Images(){
    return $this->hasMany(ProductImages::class, 'id_product', 'id_product');
}
```

Model Images

```
protected $table = 'product_images';

protected $primaryKey = 'id_image';

protected $fillable = [
    'id_image', 'id_product', 'image',
];

public function Products(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Products::class, 'id_product', 'id_product');
}
```

Comment: Your keys are wrong, `'id_product'` shouldn't appear twice. First is the _foreign_ key, second is the _local_ key. [One To Many](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

Comment: @brombeer still the same, the thing is it works on the first page, but when I go to the 2nd page it gives me the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like you are accessing inside loop is wrong.

Instead of `$p->images->first()->image` this.It should be

```
$p->Images->first()->image
```

So Final loop will be

```
@foreach ($products as $p)
@if($p->Images->first())

         <a href="#"><img src="{{ asset('images/products/'.$p->Images->first()->image ) }}" alt=""></a>
@endif
@endforeach
```

Also if you are looking to load only those products which has images then

```
$products = Products::with('Images')->whereHas('Images')->paginate(6);
```

Instead of using first() method in blade file.you can add another relationship hasone

```
public function Image(){ 
return $this->hasOne(ProductImages::class, 'id_product', 'id_product'); 
}
```

Comment: it still the same, it looks like it isn't case sensitive. The thing is on the first page it works like a charm, but when I go to the 2nd page it gives me the error.

Comment: look like second one doesnt have images so $products = Products::with('Images')->whereHas('Images')->paginate(6);

Comment: thank you it works, turns out there are null images for the last record so that's why it gives me the error.

Comment: if you need one route then you can define one more relationship public function Image(){
    return $this->hasOne(ProductImages::class, 'id_product', 'id_product');
}

Comment: so that no need to call first in view .you can access directly